# Google Apps Script to delete text/lines between 2 keywords

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I would like to use google apps script to copy full content of another document to current document and then perform some clean up.

The workflow I can think of is:

```
1. clear current document

    DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody().editAsText().setText('');

2. copy content from an other document (not sure what is the syntax)

3. find and delete <keyword> ..... </keyword>. It can be single line or
   pan across multiple lines and having table or diagram in between. eg.

Before
------
This is a <keyword>big black</keyword> cat.

<keyword>
Title
... table here
... diagram here
</keyword>

End of doc.


After
-----
This is a cat.


End of doc.
```

I need help in creating google app script for item #2 & #3 in above.

Comment: For clarification, I would like to implement conditional text in google doc. eg. Original Doc has some of the content marked with <keyword> .... </keyword>. Another filtered document will have the contents generated from original doc except content bounded by <keyword> and </keyword> is removed.

Comment: I think this can help you:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30578496/removing-a-paragraph-of-text

Answer (score 1):

I have a great solution here for #3.

In google docs, the text is:

```
Quero que todo o texto a seguir suma:

start
TEXTO QUE QUERO QUE SUMA
end

Será que deu certo??
```

In google script:

```
function BoldBetweenTags() {
var testeid = '1fltAxuhgfUOOdRvvIyXfLz13gxPDvtugUMyAGOK0jcE';
var body = DocumentApp.openById(testeid).getBody();
var text = body.editAsText();
var para = body.getParagraphs();

var startTag = 'start';
var endTag = 'end'

var del = "no";  

  for(var i in para){  
  Logger.log('Parágrafo: '+i)
    var from = para[i].findText(startTag);
    var to =  para[i].findText(endTag);
    if (from != null){var del = "yes";  para[i].editAsText().removeFromParent();}
    if (from == null && to == null && del == "yes"){para[i].editAsText().removeFromParent();}
    if (to != null){var del = "no";  para[i].editAsText().removeFromParent();}
}}
```

For #2 you need to

```
var folder =  DriveApp.createFolder("name of the folder");
var rep = DriveApp.getFileById('your ID');
var repi = rep.makeCopy("name of your new document", folder);
```

This works for me

Answer (score 0):

For item #3, here is my working code:

```
function deleteSection(keyword) {

  var start = ' *\<' + keyword + '\> *';
  var end   = ' *\<\/' + keyword + '\> *';

  var bodyElement = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();
  var found = 0;

  // have to do reverse else the result is incorrect
  var totalchildren = bodyElement.getNumChildren();
  for (var i=totalchildren-1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (found == 0) {
      if (bodyElement.getChild(i).asText().findText(end) !== null) {
        bodyElement.getChild(i).asText().replaceText(".*"+end,"");
        if (bodyElement.getChild(i).asText().findText("^ *$") !== null) {
          bodyElement.getChild(i).removeFromParent();
        }
        found = 1;
      }
    } else {
      if (bodyElement.getChild(i).asText().findText(start) !== null) {
        bodyElement.getChild(i).asText().replaceText(start+".*","");
        if (bodyElement.getChild(i).asText().findText("^ *$") !== null) {
          bodyElement.getChild(i).removeFromParent();
        }
        found = 0;
      } else {
        bodyElement.getChild(i).removeFromParent();
      }
    }  
  }
}
```