# Remove unlimited amounts of text between two text values

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-docs

I'm using the following code to delete text between a range of characters.

However, when I try to delete multiple paragraphs of text, I receive the following error:

> Index (548) must be less than the content length (377). (line 195, file "")

How I can remove unlimited amounts of text between two text values?

```
function removeCbSevHD1(X) {
    var rangeElement1 = DocumentApp.openById(X).getBody().findText('<CS1>');
    var rangeElement2 = DocumentApp.openById(X).getBody().findText('<CS2>');
    Logger.log(rangeElement1.getElement());
    if (rangeElement1.isPartial()) {
        var startOffset = rangeElement1.getStartOffset();
        var endOffset = rangeElement2.getEndOffsetInclusive();
        rangeElement1.getElement().asText().deleteText(startOffset,endOffset);}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tiny G! Thanks for all the help man.

I was able to find some help. Here's the answer:

```
function removeSection3(X) {
for (var i = 1; i <= 7; i++) {
var search = '<ZY' + i + '>';    
var rangeElement = DocumentApp.openById(X).getBody().findText(search);
if (rangeElement) {
  rangeElement.getElement().getParent().removeFromParent();
}
```

}
}

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30604543/4639281) to your previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30578496/4639281), you cannot select from the beginning of one range to the end of another range. That is what the `if (element.isPartial()) { ... } else { ... }` condition is for. If the range is the entire element, it will remove the whole element.

If you want to remove multiple ranges, then you have to remove one at a time.

In the following example I do this by looping through an array of search strings and applying the function to each.

```js
function removeCbSevHD1(X) {
    // If you want to add more things to match and remove, add to this array
    var search = /<CS1>.*<CS2>/;
    var rangeElement = DocumentApp.openById(X).getBody().findText(search);
    if (rangeElement.isPartial()) {
        var startOffset = rangeElement.getStartOffset();
        var endOffset = rangeElement.getEndOffsetInclusive();
        rangeElement.getElement().asText().deleteText(startOffset,endOffset);
    } else {
        rangeElement.getElement().removeFromParent();
    }
}
```

<sub>**Note:** Not tested.</sub>

Comment: Thanks Tiny. I tried the new version and it does remove CS1, and CS2, but it doesnt remove the text between the ranges. In the previous answer you gave me we used "var rangeElement1 = DocumentApp.openById(X).getBody().findText('<CS1>');
var rangeElement2 = DocumentApp.openById(X).getBody().findText('<CS2>');". Would we have to add something similar to this new looping function?

Comment: @JordanThibodeau I've updated the script, try the new revision. Would you be able to make a fiddle set up for an actual document I can work with so I don't have to set one up?

Comment: Go to http://jsfiddle.com and set your script up in there, make it reproduce the error then save it and copy the url and post it here.

Comment: Or, just make a [gist](http://gist.github.com) or a [paste](http://pastebin.com) of your entire script and post the link here