# Delete contents of an entire Range in Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I am trying to delete everything inside of a Range in a Document using the following code. It is able to get the RangeElements from the range, but it apparently leaves the document in a strange state after this operation, making code elsewhere in my app unusable.

Code depending on the document that this Range is a part of throws an error later on. I am unsure if it is due to this code specifically, or if I need to do some other step to put the document into a different editable state.

```
/**
 * Deletes the range and all of its RangeElements.
 */
function removeRange (range) {
  Logger.log('removeRange called with range:' + range)

  var rangeElements = range.getRangeElements()

  Logger.log('removing ' + rangeElements.length + ' rangeElements')
  for (var i = 0; i < rangeElements.length; i++) {
    var rangeElement = rangeElements[i]

    // http://stackoverflow.com/a/30604543/5465037
    if (rangeElement.isPartial()) {
      // It's partial!
      Logger.log('it\'s partial!')
      var startOffset = rangeElement.getStartOffset()
      var endOffset = rangeElement.getEndOffsetInclusive()
      rangeElement.getElement().asText().deleteText(startOffset, endOffset)
    } else {
      rangeElement.getElement().removeFromParent()
    }
  }

  Logger.log('removeRange finished.')
}
```

**Edit:** I am calling the code below to get the range based on my own placeholders in the Google Doc. The placeholders are of the format `{tagIdHere}` and `{/tagIdHere}`. This code does replace the tags with `' '`, but I am unable to remove the Range returned by this function properly.

```
/**
 * Gets a range between the two tags, removing the tags.
 */
function getRangeBetweenAndRemoveTags (doc, tagId) {
  var rangeBuilder = doc.newRange()

  var startTag = '{' + tagId + '}'
  var endTag = '{/' + tagId + '}'

  var body = doc.getBody()
  var startElement = body.replaceText(startTag, ' ')
  var endElement = body.replaceText(endTag, ' ')

  Logger.log('startElement: ' + startElement)
  Logger.log('endElement: ' + endElement)

  rangeBuilder.addElementsBetween(startElement, endElement)

  var range = rangeBuilder.build()

  return range
}
```